# How to send an email to outlook in laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to send email to `outlook` in `laravel 5.6`

**.env file**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.office365.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=******
MAIL_PASSWORD="******"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

**config/mail.php**

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.office365.com'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'kishor.bhatt@cdscnp.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Kishor Bhatt'),
],
 'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
 'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

 'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
```

**email/mail.blade.php**

```
<h3>You have received new email.</h3>
<div>
<b>Name:</b> {{ $name }} <br>
<b>Email:</b> {{ $email }} <br>
<b>Phone No:</b> {{ $phone }} <br>
<div> 
<b>Message:</b> {{ $bodyMessage }}
</div>
</div>
<p> Send By: {{ $email }} <p>
```

**sendmail() function**

```
    $data = $request->all();
    $mail = array(
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'phone' => $data['phone'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'bodyMessage' => $data['message']
        );

        Mail::send('email.mail', $mail, function($message) use ($mail){
            $message->from($mail['email']);
            $message->to('shankar.bhatt@cdscnp.com');
            $message->subject('Query from '.$mail['name']);
        });

      return redirect('/contact-us')->with('flash_message_success','Thank you for your feedback. We will get back shortly.');
```

**Error:**

> Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username
>   "prem.basnet@cdscnp.com" using 2 possible authenticators.
>   Authenticator LOGIN returned Swift_TransportException: Expected
>   response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535 5.7.3
>   Authentication unsuccessful.

How do I solve the error and send the email to outlook?

Comment: I've edited your question to remove sensitive information from the .env file. I see you set the password in quotes in the .env file, did you try without putting it inside `""`?

Comment: yes..i have used " " in password

Comment: How do i solve this problem...

Comment: Please revisit [prior similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+535%205.7.3%20Authentication%20unsuccessful.%20phpmailer%20office365). Add a list of things already tried. There's no point in guessing the auth failure cause.

Comment: i have tried..but not working..email is not sending..

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in laravel 5.8 with an exchange server. 
I solved this by doing this in the .env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp

MAIL_HOST=ipadress

MAIL_PORT=587

MAIL_USERNAME="*******"

MAIL_PASSWORD="********"

MAIL_ENCRYPTION=''
```