# How to send mail from outlook in laravel?

Tags: laravel, outlook, laravel-mail

I want to send mail from outlook in Laravel and i really don't know how my .env configuration file will look like. At the moment this is what my .env configuration file looks like:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp-mail.outlook.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=****
MAIL_PASSWORD="******"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tsl
```

Comment: Since your configurations matches this... MAIL_DRIVER=smtp MAIL_HOST=smtp-mail.outlook.com MAIL_PORT=587 MAIL_USERNAME=MyOutlookAccount MAIL_PASSWORD=MyOutlookPassword MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls Your .env configurations should work... Or whats the error message generated??? Or see: [here about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54529731/how-to-send-an-email-to-outlook-in-laravel-5-6)

Comment: Check that those ports are open from the server you are using to send the requests too. Sometimes ports are blocked.